# Retain focus in TextBox if surrounding elements are clicked

Tags: c#, silverlight

I have a small user control that contains some Xaml markup that includes a TextBox.  When the control is selected, I automatically set focus on the TextBox.  However, when the user clicks on any other element (such as a border) the focus is removed from the TextBox.

For example,

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>

  <Rectangle Grid.Row="0" Fill="Blue" IsHitTestVisible="False" />
  <TextBox Grid.Row="1" />
  <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Text="Something" IsHitTestVisible="False" />
</Grid>
```

Clicking either the Rectangle or the TextBlock causes the TextBox to lose focus.

What's the best way to retain focus on the TextBlock?  I feel I'm missing something simple.

Comment: Perhaps you could handle the LostFocus event and call Focus when it happens? Are you trying to have a custom looking TextBox? You should look into Templates & Styles if so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution I found was to rebuild the Xaml surrounding the control in question so that custom control incorporated everything that I wanted to not affect the the focus of the text box.  And then put a handler on the mouse event to ensure that the TextBox retained focus.

I was not happy with the solution but couldn't think of anything else.

( I did try to handle the LostFocus event and determine if the mouse was still the user control, but gave up with that route when I had to continually keep track of the mouse location ).

Answer (score 0):

The click is probably going through the grid and giving focus to whatever is under it.

Try setting Background="Transparent" on the `<Grid>`